# Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics Download failed

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crashlytics

When I add Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics nuget packages, these errors appear:

> Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/11.4.2/play-services-basement-11.4.2.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\playservices-11.4.2/playservicesbasement.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/11.4.2/play-services-tasks-11.4.2.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\playservices-11.4.2/playservicestasks.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-analytics-impl/11.4.2/firebase-analytics-impl-11.4.2.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\firebase-11.4.2/firebaseanalyticsimpl.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-analytics/11.4.2/firebase-analytics-11.4.2.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\firebase-11.4.2/firebaseanalytics.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/11.4.2/firebase-common-11.4.2.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\firebase-11.4.2/firebasecommon.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/11.4.2/firebase-iid-11.4.2.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\firebase-11.4.2/firebaseiid.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download 
>   https://maven.google.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers/1.4.2/answers-1.4.2.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\crashlyticsanswers-1.4.2.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download
>   https://maven.google.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/beta/1.2.9/beta-1.2.9.aar
>   to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\crashlyticsbeta-1.2.9.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download  " crashlyticscore link "  to a file
>   called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\crashlyticscore-2.6.3.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download  " crashlytics link "  to a file
>   called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\crashlytics-2.9.4.aar.
>
> Download failed. Please download  "fabric link"  to a file called
>   C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\fabric-1.4.3.aar.

Comment: Where is the location?

Comment: solution? desktop

Comment: There are some dependencies  you need to install  ,check the workaround : https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/460#issuecomment-532676292 ,maybe helpful.

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: where are you location(country) ?

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, turkey

Comment: Are you able to go to those locations and download those dependencies yourself, and put them in the proper locations?